# Hide the port number from node js and angular8

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular8

I want to hide the port number from my website URL. My website is in the nodejs and Angular8 and for the node js we are using 3001 port in HTTPS request and for angular, we are using 4224 port in the HTTP request.

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Use the default ports (443/https or 80/http) on the external-facing server (which could be a proxy). Non-default ports *must* be specified in the URI.